# How to Create Boundaries in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am new to AS3 and I wanted to know how to make a frame Boundary in flash, I am making a platformer  game. My code Logic is like :

Whenever I move with ArrowKeys Move Background invert, so if I click Left key the background will move Left. so this is not really what I want as my Player (moving avatar) will always be stick to the middle of the stage. How to make a New boundary so whenever Player go near Right end of Stage ... Background should go left as much x moved outside boundary of player.

more illustration :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwc9V.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(player.x > rightBound){
  map.x += rightBound - player.x;
  player.x = rightBound;
}
```

Repeat for the other 3 sides.